# What is the role of--blue in CSS code in bootstrap?

Tags: css

What is the role  like of "--blue" in CSS code in bootstrap? If changing the default color value, where do I have references?

```
:root {
  --blue: #007bff;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
  --purple: #6f42c1;
  --pink: #e83e8c;
  --red: #dc3545;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are [Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) also known as `CSS variables` that can be used in your `CSS` file using `var()` function.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)

> Property names that are prefixed with --, like --example-name,
>   represent custom properties that contain a value that can be used in
>   other declarations using the var() function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a css var, so you can search `var(--blue)` in your code to see where the var is used

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/var()

(sorry for my english ^^)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.